# Elasticsearch Return Only Geometry (location) field

Tags: elasticsearch

Does anyone know if it is possible in ElasticSearch to return only the location field?

I have a need to perform a query and only return the geometries associated with each document; I dont need the rest of the attributes.

I've tried the "fields", but that does not return the location field.

"fields" : ["location"]

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html

Comment: Not what you asked, but is there something preventing you from picking just the location from the resultset and using it?

Comment: As in further processing of the result? That would mean iterating through the entire results array to create a new array with all values stripped out except for the GeoSJON. I do not want to perform any additional result processing; need to keep this as fast as possible so that means only returning the raw ES response from my API.